# Error in TensorFlow Model Training: Assertion Failed in Sparse Categorical Crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech

I'm encountering an issue while trying to train a TensorFlow model for a text-to-speech task using MFCC features. I've followed the instructions to build a Transformer-based model for my audio data, but I'm facing an error during the training process. I'm using the sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss function, and the error message suggests a shape mismatch between my predicted outputs and the true labels.

Error Message:

```
assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [32 1] [y (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [32 1392]
```

Here's a summary of the relevant parts of my code:

Loading and Preprocessing Data:

```
# ... (imports and other code)

# Loading MFCC features
processed_data = np.load("processed_data.npz")
mfccs = processed_data["mfccs"]
labels = processed_data["labels"]

# Splitting the data into training, validation, and test sets
train_mfccs, val_test_mfccs, train_labels, val_test_labels = train_test_split(mfccs, labels, test_size=0.2)
val_mfccs, test_mfccs, val_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(val_test_mfccs, val_test_labels, test_size=0.5)

# Transposing the MFCC features
train_mfccs = np.transpose(train_mfccs, (0, 2, 1))
val_mfccs = np.transpose(val_mfccs, (0, 2, 1))
test_mfccs = np.transpose(test_mfccs, (0, 2, 1))

# ... (label preprocessing and encoding)
```

Building the Transformer Model:

```
# ... (imports and other code)

# Defining the scaled dot product attention function
def scaled_dot_product_attention(query, key, value, mask=None):
    # ... (attention calculations)

# Defining the Multi-Head Attention layer
class MultiHeadAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    # ... (constructor and split_heads method)

    def call(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        # ... (transformations and attention calculation)
```

Creating the Model:

```
# ... (imports and other code)

# Building the model using the Keras Functional API
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 13))  # 13 MFCC features
attention_output = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)(input, input, input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(attention_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training the Model:

```
# ... (imports and other code)

# Training the model
history = model.fit(train_mfccs, train_labels,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(val_mfccs, val_labels))

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_mfccs, test_labels)
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss}, Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy}")
```

I suspect the issue might be related to the number of units in the final dense layer of my model not matching the number of classes in my target vocabulary. However, I've ensured that my label encoding and preprocessing are consistent with the model's requirements.

Why am I encountering this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].